# how to split one row into multiple rows in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have table looks like this

```
Col1     col2    col3     col4        col5
---------------------------------------------
data1    data2   data3    data4       data5
```

I want to display that record as

```
heading1      heading2
----------------------
Col1          data1
Col2          data2
col3          data3
col4          data4
col5          data5
```

Comment: Hint: UNPIVOT :)

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2005 like your title says? If so, the `UNPIVOT` command won't work. It wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2008.

Comment: UNPIVOT  is working perfectly in Sql server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNPIVOT` to achive this:

```
select P.Heading1, P.Heading2
from Temp T
unpivot
(
  Heading2
  for Heading1 in (Col1,col2,col3,col4, col5)
) P;
```

More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot).

Comment: If the title is right and they are using SQL Server 2005, the `UNPIVOT` command won't work. This command wasn't introduced until SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @virusstorm the documentation is misleading. PIVOT and UNPIVOT were introduced in sql 2005. That version was removed from the documentation because it is no longer in mainstream support.

Answer (score 0):

See this small example:

```
SELECT * INTO T FROM
(VALUES
(1,2,3)
) T(A,B,C)

SELECT * FROM T
```

Base table:

```
A B C
- - -
1 2 3
```

Unpivot:

```
SELECT * FROM T
UNPIVOT (X FOR Y IN (A,B,C)) U
```

Result

```
X Y
- -
1 A
2 B
3 C
```

Comment: SELECT Y,X FROM T
UNPIVOT (X FOR Y IN (A,B,C)) U  would be correct. Thanks

Comment: And the dataType and size of the column should be same to this query to work

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TempData') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TempData
;With cte(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5)
AS
(
SELECT 'data1','data2','data3','data4','data5'
)
SELECT * INTO TempData FROM cte

SELECT  * FROM TempData
```

Using Cross Apply an dynamic Sql

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) , @dynCoulmn NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @dynCoulmn=STUFF((SELECT distinct ', '+TempCol  FROM
(
SELECT '('+COLUMN_NAME+','+''''+COLUMN_NAME+''''+')' AS TempCol
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='TempData'
)dt2
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

SET @Sql=' 
SELECT heading1,heading2 FROM TempData
CROSS APPLY ( Values '+@dynCoulmn+'
            ) A (heading2,heading1)
            '
PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

Result before cross apply

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
-------------------------------------
data1   data2   data3   data4   data5
```

Result Aftercross apply

```
heading1    heading2
---------------------
Col1         data1
Col2         data2
Col3         data3
Col4         data4
Col5         data5
```